# How to manage timezone difference in order created date while creating order programatically

Tags: magento2

I am creating order programmatically on magento 2.2 and using this

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($order_id);
$order->setCreatedAt($orderData['created_at']); 
$order->save();
```

where `$this->orderRepository` referes to 
`\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository`

The created_date comes from an excel and has the 
date (2019-01-11 18:43:08)
 , but created_at coloumn under sales_order it is saved as  2019-01-12 00:13:07 . 
[image]

. Here are the timezone settings that i have in backend [image]

I need to have the same dates  in order that i have in csv and and same need to be reflected on other places like order grid. Please advice

Comment: which version you have using?

Comment: Hi amit i am using magento 2.2.5

Comment: up !!!! , I have the same problem when created_at in sales_order DB lately with purchase date in Orders Grid Admin Magento 2.2.3